# how to change the size of the imported image used as turtle stamp

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have followed the procedure to add an image to turtle screen and stamp with it. such as

```
>>> from turtle import Screen, Turtle
>>> screen=Screen()
>>> image='leaves.gif'
>>> screen.register_shape(image)
>>> t=Turtle(image)
>>> t.stamp()
   5
>>> t.shapesize(1,1,1)
>>> t.fd(400)
>>> t.stamp()
   6
>>> t.rt(90)
>>> t.fd(400)
>>> t.shapesize(10,10,5)
>>> t.stamp()
    7
>>> t.rt(90)
>>> t.fd(400)
```

So, I am trying to change the size and orientation of the turtle stamp, but it remains the same as the original image. Can this be done?

Also what is the sequential number that shows up.

Comment: No one answered this. However, I found the answer: Here is the code:   from tkinter import PhotoImage;
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, Shape;

screen = Screen();

#  'subsample' for 'smaller; zoom' for larger;
larger = PhotoImage(file="leaves.gif").zoom(2, 2);

screen.addshape("larger", Shape("image", larger));

turtle = Turtle("larger");
turtle.hideturtle();

turtle.stamp();

turtle.fd(400);

smaller = PhotoImage(file="leaves.gif").subsample(4, 4);

screen.addshape("smaller", Shape("image", smaller));

turtle = Turtle("smaller");

turtle.stamp();

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to change the ... orientation of the turtle stamp, but it remains the same as the original image. Can this be done?

Not according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html):

> Note: Image shapes do not rotate when turning the turtle, so they do
> not display the heading of the turtle!

Addressing your other question:

> Also what is the sequential number that shows up[?]

Again, according to the documentation:

> Return[s] a stamp_id for that stamp, which can be used to delete it by
> calling clearstamp(stamp_id).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.